Render problem when testing react component
Hello I am trying to make a test for filtering columns, when I filter one column, it will say ´1 kolonner skjult´, if I filter 2 it will say 2 instead. When I make individual tests for these, they work as expected but I am trying to make a test where we first filter one, then make a click to filter one more, and then checking if the text has changed by rendering it, but it looks like the text just get appended and I have no idea why?? Here is the code
// Define the initial visible columns
const alleKolonner: Array<TabellKolonne<Melding>> = meldingtabellKolonner();

const setSkjulteKolonner = vi.fn();

describe('MeldingtabellFiltrerKolonnerModule komponent', () => {
  const renderComponent = (synligeKolonner: Array<TabellKolonne<Melding>>) =>
    render(
      <MeldingtabellFiltrerKolonner
        synligeKolonner={synligeKolonner}
        setSkjulteKolonner={setSkjulteKolonner}
        alleKolonner={alleKolonner}
      />
    );
    
    it('skal kalle setSkjulteKolonner når en kolonne velges eller fjernes og endrer antall skjulte kolonner', () => {
    const synligeKolonner = alleKolonner.slice(0, alleKolonner.length - 1); // All except the last one
    renderComponent(synligeKolonner);

    // Check the initial state: should show 'Vis/Skjul Kolonner'
    const dropdown = screen.getByRole('combobox', {
      name: '1 kolonner skjult',
    });
    expect(dropdown).toBeInTheDocument();

    // Click to open the dropdown and hide one column
    fireEvent.mouseDown(dropdown);
    const kolonneToOption = screen.getByText(alleKolonner[1].tittel);
    fireEvent.click(kolonneToOption);
    expect(setSkjulteKolonner).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Function));
    const update = setSkjulteKolonner.mock.calls[0][0];
    const updatedState = update(synligeKolonner);

    // Filter out the hidden column
    const oppdatertKolonne = synligeKolonner.filter(
      (kolonne) => kolonne.tittel !== updatedState[0].tittel
    );

    // Re-render the component with the updated state
    renderComponent(oppdatertKolonne);

    // Check if the dropdown now shows "1 kolonne skjult"
    const updatedDropdown = screen.getByRole('combobox', {
      name: '2 kolonner skjult',
    });
    expect(updatedDropdown).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

The first check on the dropdown passes, but the last one, returns that we cant find "2 kolonner skjult" it finds "1 kolonner skjult 2 kolonner skjult" instead.
Any help would be appreciated, tried everything I could think of

Did you try to add a await waitFor around your check? It is very likely that this will fix it.

did my soltuion work for you?

I had stuff like this happen to me as well. I assume that you use react-testing-library.
Very often when you try to do tests where a component needs to rerender due to some inner state changes it makes sense to add an await waitFor() around your query and expect. It is descirbed in the docs.
    // Note the it() function must be async 
   
    // Re-render the component with the updated state
    renderComponent(oppdatertKolonne);
    
    await waitFor(() => {
      // Check if the dropdown now shows "1 kolonne skjult"
      const updatedDropdown = screen.getByRole('combobox', {
        name: '2 kolonner skjult',
      });
      expect(updatedDropdown).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

As I understand, basically not all state update and renders did happen when your tests reaches the line where you query and then do the expect. If you now use the waitFor The code will rexecute until it passes or the timeout is reached.
